# Relações entre Models PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Olá!

Eu estou desenvolvendo um miniframework, para meus projetos, e tbm criar mais conhecimentos a respeito da orientação à objeto no PHP

Eu criei, uma MODEL onde faz boa parte de tudo, e minhas classes estendem essa MODEL.... Até agora está praticamente tudo funcionando, insert, update, delete, findAll, findAllByPk, FindAllByAttributes etc.

Mas o que eu queria fazer agora são as relações entre as classes.
Ex:Eu tenho uma classe **Produto**  e uma **Categoria**, onde todo produto possui uma categoria.

Na hora de mostrar isso na view, eu queria chamar da seguinte forma:

> $Produto->Categoria->attribute_categoria

mas até agora estou sem sucesso, agradeço quem puder me ajudar (me dá um norte) de como fazer isso.

Comment: Mano acho que vc nao foi muito feliz ao finalizar a explicação do seu texto, post um exemplo do que vc ja tem, e oque voce quer, fica melhor para visualizarmos sua ideal e ajudar em uma solução

Answer (score 1):

O que eu faria se fosse você seria o seguinte:

```
class Produto
{

  protected $objCategoria; //faça get's end seter's
  protected $idCategoria;  //faça get's end seter's
  ...

  protected function getCategoriaProduto($idCategoria){
     $this->$categoria = new Categoria($idCategoria);
  }

  public function getProduto($idProduto){
    //processamento para pegar produto
    $this->getCategoriaProduto($this->$idCategoria);  
  }
}
```

O que eu fiz foi criar uma propriedade objCategoria, que armazena um objeto da classe categoria(que tem que ser definido por você), isso quando você faz uma pesquisa no produto através de um método getProdutos, por exemplo. Tal método cria uma instância da classe Categoria, que alimenta a propriedade objCategoria.

para melhor se encaixar no que você já fez, você pode alimentar o $objCategoria com um findAllByPk da classe Categoria, dentro do seu método findAllByPk da Classe produto.